# Populate a table with XML data (using Nokigiri/xpath)

Tags: ruby, xml, xpath, nokogiri

I'm utilizing the Bing API to gather stats from an ad campaign.  I have an XML document with all the values I need that looks like this:

xml_source

```
<Table>
 <Row>
  <CampaignName value="Air Duct Cleaning" />
  <Status value="Active" />
  <Impressions value="1302" />
  <Clicks value="39" />
 </Row>
 <Row>
  <CampaignName value="Carpet Cleaning" />
  <Status value="Active" />
  <Impressions value="6946" />
  <Clicks value="130" />
 </Row>
 <Row>
  <CampaignName value="Brand Terms" />
  <Status value="Active" />
  <Impressions value="5012" />
  <Clicks value="196" />
 </Row>
</Table>
```

I'd like to setup a table in my view that ends up looking like:

View

```
<table>
 <tr>
  <td>Air Duct Cleaning</td>
  <td>Active</td>
  <td>1302</td>
  <td>39</td>
  ...
```

I have it set as a Nokogiri::XML::Document

```
doc = Nokogiri::XML(xml_source)
doc2 = doc.remove_namespaces!

bingstats = doc2.xpath("//CampaignName", "//Status", "//Impressions", "//Clicks")  #creates a Nokogiri::XML::Nodeset
```

To get the values for each of those -

```
stats = bingstats.map {|map| map.values}
# => [["Air Duct Cleaning"], ["Carpet Cleaning"], ["Brand Terms"], ["active"], ["active"], ["active"], ["1302"], ["6946"], ["5012"], ["39"], ["130"], ["196"]
```

Am I using that xpath properly?  Do I need to ref the //Table/Row elements? How can I set it up so that the items can pair together in the table?

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A better way would be to first query the XML for all `Row` elements, giving a node set you can iterate over:

```
bingstats = doc2.xpath("//Row")
```

You can now iterate over the `Rows` and fetch the data associated with each one with another XPath query starting from the `Row` node, so the data for each campaign is kept together For example:

```
bingstats.each do |row|
  name = row.at_xpath("CampaignName/@value")
  status = row.at_xpath("Status/@value")
  impressions = row.at_xpath("Impressions/@value")
  clicks = row.at_xpath("Clicks/@value")

  #...
end
```

You could even do this in your view – if you’re using Erb this would look something like:

```
<table>
  <% bingstats.each do |row| %>
    <tr>
      <td><%= row.at_xpath("CampaignName/@value") %></td>
      <td><%= row.at_xpath("Status/@value") %></td>
      <td><%= row.at_xpath("Impressions/@value") %></td>
      <td><%= row.at_xpath("Clicks/@value") %></td>
    </tr>
  <% end %>
</table>
```

You might need to make `bingstats` an instance variable (i.e. `@bingstats`) if you do this, so the variable is available in the view.

Comment: Matt - Thank you for the response! That got me really close.  I implemented your suggestions in the view and the output of each <td> was an `Nokogiri::XML::Element`.  I called `.values` like `row.at_xpath("CampaignName").values` and the output for each <td> ended up being the result in a single element array like `["Air Duct Cleaning"]` - how should I pull it out of there?

Comment: You could do `row.at_xpath("CampaignName").values.first`, but it would be better to do something like: `row.at_xpath("CampaignName/@value")`.

Comment: @macoughl I’ve updated the answer with better XPath queries that extract the `value` you want. They should now give what you’re after.

Comment: Perfect! Thank you both.  Can you give me a quick explanation or point me at what I should research to understand the syntax `/@value` in `("CampaignName/@value")`?  I would have never known I was able to add that there to essentially replace that `.values` call I used in my first comment.